# Ionic 2 - Show notification when app is in foreground on IOS

Tags: ios, cordova, notifications, ionic2

I am making a chat application in Ionic 2. I want notifications to appear even when app is in foreground. I have tried using Phonegap Plugin Push and FCM Plugin both and I'm getting notifications when app is in background and when app is killed.

But these plugins didn't show notifications when app is in foreground. So I used Local Notifications Plugin by Katzer. It works for Android perfectly but in IOS I'm facing multiple issues.

When used with Phonegap Plugin Push, the local notification does appear but its click event does not work. Also, the two plugins seem to have some conflicts so when used together, sometimes normal push notifications does not arrive or their click events does not work.
When used with FCM plugin, no local notification arrived.

I also tried using phonegap-plugin-local-notification but again it worked for Android but in IOS, notification arrives in form of alert and also its click event gets called automatically.

I am stuck on this for a long time. Can someone please provide a solution? All I want is to get notification in the notification center when app is in foreground in IOS and also a click event so I can do redirection on click.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Some code would make it much easier for fellow developers to understand your issue. Please try to be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

I was implementing in my cordova app [this plugin](https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/PushNotification).

And when device ready I fired this code:

```
pushNotification.register(
function (result) {
    //Do some stuff
}, function (error) {
    //Do some stuff on error 
}, {
    "badge":"true",
    "sound":"true",
    "alert":"true",
    "ecb": "onNotificationAPN"
});
```

And also implemented below function:

```
function onNotificationAPN(event) {
  if (event) {
    if ( event.alert ) {
      alert(Recieved alert: + event.alert);
    }
    if ( event.sound ) {
      var snd = new Media(event.sound);
      snd.play();
    }
    if ( event.badge ) {
      pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(function() {
        //SetApplicationIconBadgeNumber success.
      }, function() {
        //SetApplicationIconBadgeNumber error.
      },
      event.badge);
    }
  }
}
```

And I am able to receive notifications also in foreground.